# Plotly.js `npm run custom-bundle` generates empty file (only header is included)

Tags: npm, plotly.js, npm-package

I followed instructions from this tutorial [CUSTOM BUNDLE](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/CUSTOM_BUNDLE.md) but even example command
`npm run custom-bundle -- --unminified --out myScatters --traces scatter,scattergl,scatter3d --transforms none` generates empty file like this:

```
/**
* plotly.js (myScatters) v2.20.0
* Copyright 2012-2023, Plotly, Inc.
* All rights reserved.
* Licensed under the MIT license
*/
```

and actual JS source is missing.

Does anybody know where is the problem? Plotly.js version is `2.20.0`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that the reason behind this is outdated `nodejs`/`npm` (probably not compatible with `plotly.js v2.20.0`).

After updating `node` to the version `v19.8.1` and `npm` to `9.6.2`, `npm run custom-build` works.